# How can I Find ID from table where the selected id have the least number of days [min(datediff(day,datefrom,dateto))]?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find only Id from my table.

the condition is, the selected id have the least number of days validity

Like

```
min(datediff(day,datefrom,dateto))
```

Comment: Please add few more details with sample input or output

Comment: please write the structure of your table

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 1 id from table_name 
order by datediff(day,datefrom,dateto)
```

Try this out!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer Yeah sure.
order by datediff(day,datefrom,dateto) will find the difference between the two dates and will return the no. of days, simultaneously ordering the result set in ascending order. Rest of the work is just to fetch the top most id value using 'top 1 id'

Answer (score 0):

To get the one with the lowest datediff, you can use top 1 and order on datediff

```
select top 1 id
from @t
order by datediff(day, datefrom, dateto)
```

You change @t to your table name